# Show product attribute instead of prodict Name

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to show product attribute instead of the product name (title) globally on the frontend for Magento 2? Basically every product has a custom attribute 'frontend_name' which must appear everywhere on the frontend (breadcrumbs, product page, cart, and so on) instead of the product name.

Maybe somewhere in Magento 2 core exists a method to get product name/title so I can put I plugin to extend/rewrite it?

My Magento version 2.3.2

Thanks